# Single Table Design - DynamoDB - Merge two tables into one?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've watched [this video](https://youtu.be/0iGR8GnIItQ?t=1287) and I was thinking about the Single Table Design. Is it a good idea to merge these two tables into one, just like the example in the video? Since they are related to each other (user trades and user transfers i.e. deposits and withdrawals) and the access patterns are all about given an exchange name and an account name.

[image]

The access patterns I'm interested in right now:

- Get the last user transfer for a given exchange and an account name.
- Get all user trades by date range.
- Get all user transfers by date range.

Is it a good idea to merge both tables into one with the same PK and SK? There will be items with SK `TradeDate#12/17/2022` and others with `TransferDate#12/17/2022`.

I'm about to figure out how to do the date range queries. I would have to use GSIs.

### User Trades

```
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|              PK               |                   SK                   | Account | Exchange | Fee | FeeCurrency | Instrument | Price | ProductType | Quantity |           TradeDate           |  TradeId  |             UpdatedAt             |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+
| Exchange#Binance#Account#main | TradeDate#12/17/2022 4:59:12 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:17:56.436+00:00 | 814696766 | 2023-01-26T23:17:57.7786154+00:00 |
| Exchange#Binance#Account#main | TradeDate#12/17/2022 5:38:23 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:06.876+00:00 | 814746356 | 2023-01-26T23:57:08.3696852+00:00 |
| Exchange#FTX#Account#main     | TradeDate#12/17/2021 5:38:23 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:21.226+00:00 | 814746461 | 2023-01-26T23:57:21.8543695+00:00 |
| Exchange#FTX#Account#main     | TradeDate#12/19/2022 4:59:12 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:21.901+00:00 | 814746513 | 2023-01-26T23:57:22.528155+00:00  |
| Exchange#Binance#Account#main | TradeDate#12/17/2022 4:59:12 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:22.348+00:00 | 814746517 | 2023-01-26T23:57:22.9753506+00:00 |
| Exchange#Binance#Account#main | TradeDate#12/17/2022 5:38:23 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:22.802+00:00 | 814746518 | 2023-01-26T23:57:23.429097+00:00  |
| Exchange#FTX#Account#main     | TradeDate#12/17/2021 5:38:23 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:23.252+00:00 | 814746521 | 2023-01-26T23:57:23.8756532+00:00 |
| Exchange#FTX#Account#main     | TradeDate#12/19/2022 4:59:12 PM +02:00 | main    | Binance  |   0 | BNB         | BTCBUSD    |     0 | Spot        |  0.00086 | 2023-01-26T23:57:23.759+00:00 | 814746524 | 2023-01-26T23:57:24.3824745+00:00 |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------+----------+-----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------+----------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+
```

### User Transfers (Deposits + Withdrawals)

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
|              PK               |                    SK                     | Account |                  Address                   | AddressTag | Exchange | Instrument | Network | Quantity  | TransactionFee |                           TransactionId                            |       TransferDate        |            TransferId            | TransferType |          UpdatedAt           |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
| Exchange#Binance#Account#main | TransferDate#12/17/2022 4:59:12 PM +02:00 | main    | 0xF76d3f20bF155681b0b983bFC3ea5fe43A2A6E3c | null       | Binance  | USDT       | ETH     | 97.500139 |            3.2 | 0x46d28f7d0e1e5b1d074a65dcfbb9d90b3bcdc7e6fca6b1f1f7abb5ab219feb24 | 2022-12-17T16:59:12+02:00 | 1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 |            0 | 2023-01-28T20:19:59.9181573Z |
| Exchange#Binance#Account#main | TransferDate#12/17/2022 5:38:23 PM +02:00 | main    | 0xF76d3f20bF155681b0b983bFC3ea5fe43A2A6E3c | null       | Binance  | USDT       | ETH     | 3107.4889 |            3.2 | 0xbb2b92030b988a0184ba02e2e754b7a7f0f963c496c4e3473509c6fe6b54a41d | 2022-12-17T17:38:23+02:00 | 4747f6ecc74f4dd8a4b565e0f15bcf79 |            0 | 2023-01-28T20:20:00.4536839Z |
| Exchange#FTX#Account#main     | TransferDate#12/17/2021 5:38:23 PM +02:00 | main    | 0x476d3f20bF155681b0b983bFC3ea5fe43A2A6E3c | null       | FTX      | USDT       | ETH     |        20 |            3.2 | 0xaa2b92030b988a0184ba02e2e754b7a7f0f963c496c4e3473509c6fe6b54a41d | 2021-12-17T17:38:23+02:00 | 4747f6ecc74f4dd8a4b565e0f15bcf79 |            0 | 2023-01-28T20:20:00.5723855Z |
| Exchange#FTX#Account#main     | TransferDate#12/19/2022 4:59:12 PM +02:00 | main    | 0xc46d3f20bF155681b0b983bFC3ea5fe43A2A6E3c | null       | FTX      | USDT       | ETH     |        15 |            3.2 | 0xddd28f7d0e1e5b1d074a65dcfbb9d90b3bcdc7e6fca6b1f1f7abb5ab219feb24 | 2022-12-19T16:59:12+02:00 | 1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 |            0 | 2023-01-28T20:20:00.5207119Z |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

```cs
public async Task<UserTransferDto?> GetLastAsync(string exchange, string account)
{
    var queryRequest = new QueryRequest
    {
        TableName = TableName,
        KeyConditionExpression = "#pk = :pk",
        ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "#pk", "PK" }
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            { ":pk", new AttributeValue { S = $"Exchange#{exchange}#Account#{account}" } }
        },
        ScanIndexForward = false,
        Limit = 1
    };

    var response = await _dynamoDb.QueryAsync(queryRequest);
    if (response.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var itemAsDocument = Document.FromAttributeMap(response.Items[0]);
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserTransferDto>(itemAsDocument.ToJson());;
}
```

### A little edit:

I realized I needed the transfer type too, so I changed `SK` to `TransferType#Withdraw#TransferDate#2022-12-17 14:59:12`

and now the code looks like:

```cs
public async Task<UserTransferDto?> GetLastAsync(string exchange, string account, TransferType transferType)
{
    var queryRequest = new QueryRequest
    {
        TableName = TableName,
        KeyConditionExpression = "#pk = :pk and begins_with(#sk, :sk)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "#pk", "PK" }, { "#sk", "SK" } },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            { ":pk", new AttributeValue { S = $"Exchange#{exchange}#Account#{account}" } },
            { ":sk", new AttributeValue { S = $"TransferType#{transferType}" } }
        },
        ScanIndexForward = false,
        Limit = 1
    };

    var response = await _dynamoDb.QueryAsync(queryRequest);
    if (response.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var itemAsDocument = Document.FromAttributeMap(response.Items[0]);
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserTransferDto>(itemAsDocument.ToJson());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query for the newest/latest item for a given partition key (pk) is possible if the sort key (sk) has a lexicographically sortable date/time representation e.g. ISO 8601. This is possible because items with the same pk value are stored in sorted order by sk.

To do this, simply issue a query for the pk + sk prefix, and supply Limit=1 and ScanIndexForward=False. For example:

```
KeyConditionExpression = "pk=:pk and begins_with(sk, :trade_prefix)"
Limit=1
ScanIndexForward=False
```

You can query for items with a given partition key (pk) and a sort key (sk) within a given range of dates using a key condition expression on the query which looks like `a BETWEEN b and c.`

For example:

```
KeyConditionExpression = "pk=:pk and sk between :t1 and :t2"
```

On the question of using DynamoDB as a simple key/value store where the value is a JSON blob, it depends on your access requirements. Some reasons not to have single JSON blob are that:

1. any update to the item means you have to rewrite the whole item which costs more WCUs
2. you can't create GSIs on most of the item's attributes because they're not top-level
3. it can makes concurrent puts more challenging

Answer (score 2):

My personal attitude - not to change anything if:

1. It works right now
2. I don't see any future risks on my system
3. There is no benefits on performance/durability/maintenance/ease of support

And coming to your question I don't see how merging two tables can help you.

I'd challenge that your table structure won't help you to cover these queries:

- Get the last user transfer for a given exchange and an account name.
- Get all user trades by date range.
- Get all user transfers by date range.

If I understand correctly you don't need to query anything by your current PK => why did you choose this PK? Of course you can solve it by using GSI but you won't get them for free and if you can restructurise your table to make your 3 queries easier I'd do that.

Hope I answered your question. Good luck, have fun)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `Get the last user transfer for a given exchange and an account name` this access pattern I'm querying by exchange and account name.

Comment: I added the C# code that does the first access pattern. Not sure about the date range ones. Haven't figured them out yet.

Comment: The code you posted. It won't get you the latest it will get you some element which might be latest and might not be. Dynamo doesn't have a function for latest/earliest. You can do several things: 
1.  If you have not too much records for one PK or for one PK with some SK prefix - you can query all of them, sort in memory, and take the latest.
2. A trick, you can always write two records for the same PK, one with SK==timestamp and one with SK=="latest". So you can query like {PK: Exchange#Binance#Account#main SK:latest}

Comment: Query for the newest item is possible if the SK has a sortable date representation. Simply issue query for PK + SK prefix, and supply Limit=1 and ScanIndexForward=False. This is possible because Items with the same partition key value are stored in sorted order by sort key.

Comment: @jarmod, that's what I'm doing

Comment: Yes, that comment was directed at @Aliaksandr who, if I read correctly, was suggesting this wasn't possible. It is possible, and is a common query pattern.

Comment: @jarmod, I wonder if it's better the keep all properties as separate attributes or to keep them as a single JSON object e.g. "Data" attribute and have "DataType" attribute, so I know which type to deserialize to?

Comment: Depends on access requirements. Some reasons not to have single JSON blob are that pretty much any update to the item means you have to rewrite the whole item which costs more WCUs, you can't create GSIs on most of the item's attributes because they're not top-level, and it can which makes concurrent puts more challenging.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, I was wrong. Didn't know that there are some order guaranties.

Comment: @jarmod thank you very much! And probably cuz of FilterExpressions. If you'd like you can post these stuff as an answer, so I can accept it.